# How to create a *working* save/load system in a text-based game?

Tags: python

With the code that we made the save/load system crashes the game.
So here is the full code I'm using (330 lines or so)

```
from os import stat
import time
import random
import math
import pickle
import os.path
file_exists = os.path.isfile("loadfile.txt")


class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, name, maxHP, shield, damageAbsorption, attack, dodge, money):
        self.name = name
        self.maxHP = maxHP
        self.HP = maxHP
        self.shield = shield
        self.damageAbsorption = damageAbsorption
        self.attack = attack
        self.dodge = dodge
        self.money = money

    def takeDamage(self, damagePoints):
        ad = damagePoints * (100-self.damageAbsorption)/100.0
        if(ad < 0):
            return
        elif ad < 0.1:
            ad = 0.1

        if (self.shield - ad) >= 0:
            self.shield -= ad
            ad = 0
        else:
            ad -= self.shield
            self.shield = 0
            self.HP -= ad
            if self.HP <= 0:
                self.death()
        return ad

    def death(self):
        print(f"{self.name} died")

    def show_stat(self):
        print(f"{self.name}: ")
        print(f"HP/MaxHP: {self.HP}/{self.maxHP}")
        print(f"shield: {self.shield}")
        print(f"damage absorption: {self.damageAbsorption}%")
        print(f"attack: {self.attack}")
        print(f"dodge: {self.dodge}%")
        print(f"possessed treasure: {self.money}")


class Player(Character):
    def CreatePlayer(maxHP, shield, damageAbsorption, attack, dodge, money):
        print("*******************")
        s = input("This is the adventure of ..")
        return Character(s, maxHP, shield, damageAbsorption, attack, dodge, money)

    def __init__(self):
        pass


class Waynode(object):
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type


class Game(object):
    player = Player()

    @staticmethod
    def input_instructions():
        print("\n<------commands------>")
        print("y/n - yes/no")
        print("help - open help menu")
        print("stat - show player stats")
        print("save - saves the game")
        #print("save - save game")
        print()

    @staticmethod
    def input_handler():
        s = input()
        if(s == "y"):
            return "True"
        elif(s == "n"):
            return "False"
        elif s == "stat":
            Game.player.show_stat()
            return "stat"
        elif(s == "help"):
            Game.input_instructions()
        elif s == "save":

            Game.askSave()
        elif s == "load":
            Game.load()
            return ""
        else:
            return s  # i am encountering a bug

    @staticmethod
    def askSave():
        ask = input("Do you want to save?\n--> ").upper()
        if ask == "Y" or ask == "YES":
            # Saves the desired class AND a chosen attribute
            print(Game.player.name)

            Save = Player(Game.player.name)
            # Creates the file and puts the data into the file
            pickle.dump(Save, open("save.dat", "wb"))
            # The file doesn't have an extension because it is a binary file and makes it easier to parse.
        elif ask == "N" or ask == "NO":
            print("Okay, maybe next time!")
            return
        else:
            print("Sorry, that does not compute with me! Please try again!")
            Game.askSave()

    @staticmethod
    def load():
        me = pickle.load(open("save.dat", "rb"))  # Loads the file
    # Prints the stats out to verify the load has successfully happened
        me.display(Player.display)

    @staticmethod
    def combat(turn):
        print()
        enemy = Character(f"enemy {random.randint(0,100)}", 2+turn/2, 0, math.sqrt(
            turn+1), turn/5, 20, random.randint(int(turn/2+5), int(turn/2 + 20)))
        enemy.show_stat()
        print()

        isPlayerTurn = random.choice([True, False])
        while Game.player.HP > 0 and enemy.HP > 0:
            time.sleep(1)
            if(isPlayerTurn):
                ran = random.randint(0, 100)
                if(ran <= enemy.dodge):
                    print(
                        f"{enemy.name} dodged {Game.player.name}'s attack ({enemy.dodge}%)")
                else:
                    ad = enemy.takeDamage(Game.player.attack)
                    print(
                        f"{Game.player.name} attacked {enemy.name} and deal {ad:.1f} damage (shield: {enemy.shield:.1f})")
            else:
                ran = random.randint(0, 100)
                if(ran <= Game.player.dodge):
                    print(
                        f"{Game.player.name} dodged {enemy.name}'s attack ({Game.player.dodge}%)")
                else:
                    ad = Game.player.takeDamage(enemy.attack)
                    print(
                        f"{enemy.name} attacked {Game.player.name} and deal {ad:.1f} damage (shield: {Game.player.shield:.1f})")
            isPlayerTurn = not isPlayerTurn

        print()

        if Game.player.HP <= 0:
            print(f"Game Over! turn:{turn}")
            Game.player.show_stat()
        else:
            print(f"you defeated {enemy.name}!")
            Game.player.money = Game.player.money + enemy.money
            print(f"you gained {enemy.money} coins")
            a = random.randint(5, 20)
            a = a/10
            Game.player.attack = Game.player.attack+a
            print(f"+{a} attack")
            d = random.randint(0, 10)
            d = d/10
            Game.player.dodge = Game.player.dodge+d
            print(f"+{d} dodge")
            b = random.randint(2, 10)
            b = b/10
            Game.player.damageAbsorption = Game.player.damageAbsorption+b
            print(f"+{b} damage absorption")
        print()


print("Welcome, Adventurer!")
time.sleep(1)
print("are you ready for a new adventure?(y/n)")

s = Game.input_handler()
while s != "True" and s != "False":
    print("please type again!(y/n)")
    s = Game.input_handler()


if s == "True":
    print("Great! you will be teleported to the entrance soon. " +
          "Remember you can always type \"help\" to read input commands and \"stat\" to see player's status")
    time.sleep(1)

    Game.player = Player.CreatePlayer(5, 2, 0, 1, 5, 50)
    Game.player.show_stat()
    print("*******************")
    print()

    turn = 1
    while Game.player.HP > 0 and Game.player.money <= 200:
        # before turn update
        # begin turn
        print(f"<---- turn {turn} ---->")
        ran = random.randint(1, 5)
        dialog = f"there are {ran} ways ahead.\n"
        ways = []
        for x in range(1, ran+1):
            ra = random.randint(1, 3)
            if ra == 1 or ra == 2:
                dialog = dialog + f"the way {x} is quiet, "
            elif ra == 3:
                dialog = dialog + \
                    f"{Game.player.name} hears noise come from depths in the way {x}, "
            ways.append(Waynode(ra))
        dialog = dialog[:-2]
        dialog = dialog + ".\n"
        print(dialog)
        time.sleep(2)
        num = input("which way you choose?(type number)")
        while True:
            if not num.isdigit():
                num = input("which way you choose?(type number)")
                continue
            else:
                n = int(num)
                if n <= 0 or n >= ran+1:
                    num = input("which way you choose?(type number)")
                    continue
                else:
                    break
        print(f"{Game.player.name} enters way {num}")
        n = int(num)
        time.sleep(1.5)

        if(ways[n-1].type == 1):
            ran = random.randint(1, 100)
            if ran <= 20:
                print("Nothing here!")
            elif ran <= 40:
                m = random.randint(5, 15)
                Game.player.money += m
                print(f"you found some coins in the chamber. (money + {m})")
            elif ran <= 60:
                Game.player.shield = Game.player.shield+3
                print(
                    f"you found a sturdy shield in the chamber. (shield+3)(total: {Game.player.shield})")
            elif ran <= 70:
                if(Game.player.HP + 3 > Game.player.maxHP):
                    Game.player.HP = Game.player.maxHP
                else:
                    Game.player.HP = Game.player.HP+3
                print(
                    f"you found a small healing potion in the chamber. (health+3)({Game.player.HP}/{Game.player.maxHP})")
            elif ran <= 90:
                Game.player.maxHP = Game.player.maxHP+1
                print(
                    f"you found a small crystal of blood in the chamber. (max HP+1)({Game.player.HP}/{Game.player.maxHP})")
            else:
                m = random.randint(20, 30)
                Game.player.money += m
                print(
                    f"you found a small pocket in the chamber. (money + {m})")

        elif(ways[n-1].type == 2):
            ran = random.randint(1, 100)
            if ran <= 30:
                print("Nothing here!")
            elif ran <= 40:
                m = random.randint(5, 15)
                Game.player.money += m
                print(f"you found some coins in the chamber. (money + {m})")
            elif ran <= 60:
                if(Game.player.HP + 3 > Game.player.maxHP):
                    Game.player.HP = Game.player.maxHP
                else:
                    Game.player.HP = Game.player.HP+3
                print(
                    f"you found a small healing potion in the chamber. (health+3)({Game.player.HP}/{Game.player.maxHP})")
            elif ran <= 80:
                Game.player.maxHP = Game.player.maxHP+1
                print(
                    f"you found a small crystal of blood in the chamber. (max HP+1)({Game.player.HP}/{Game.player.maxHP})")
            elif ran <= 90:
                Game.player.shield = Game.player.shield+1
                print(
                    f"you found a broken shield in the chamber. (shield+1)(total: {Game.player.shield})")
            else:
                Game.player.attack = Game.player.attack+1
                print(
                    f"you found a broken sword in the chamber. (attack+1)(total: {Game.player.attack})")

        else:
            ran = random.randint(1, 100)
            if ran <= 10:
                print("Nothing here! Maybe i am too nervous")
            elif ran <= 20:
                m = random.randint(5, 15)
                Game.player.money += m
                print(f"some coins in the chamber. (money + {m})")
            elif ran <= 30:
                Game.player.maxHP = Game.player.maxHP+3
                print(
                    f"you found a large crystal of blood in the chamber. (max HP+3)({Game.player.HP}/{Game.player.maxHP})")
            else:
                print("you encounter an enemy!")
                time.sleep(1)
                Game.combat(turn)

        time.sleep(1)
        print()
        print("ready for next turn? (y/n)")
        s = Game.input_handler()
        while s != "True":
            print("please type again!(y/n)")
            s = Game.input_handler()

        turn = turn+1
        print()

    if(Game.player.money >= 200):
        print(f"{Game.player.name} wins!")
elif s == "False":
    print("Okay, See you next time")
```

And here is the save/load system that isn't working at the moment. (Crashes the game)

```
@staticmethod
    def askSave():
        ask = input("Do you want to save?\n--> ").upper()
        if ask == "Y" or ask == "YES":
            # Saves the desired class AND a chosen attribute
            print(Game.player.name)

            Save = Player(Game.player.name)
            # Creates the file and puts the data into the file
            pickle.dump(Save, open("save.dat", "wb"))
            # The file doesn't have an extension because it is a binary file and makes it easier to parse.
        elif ask == "N" or ask == "NO":
            print("Okay, maybe next time!")
            return
        else:
            print("Sorry, that does not compute with me! Please try again!")
            Game.askSave()

    @staticmethod
    def load():
        me = pickle.load(open("save.dat", "rb"))  # Loads the file
    # Prints the stats out to verify the load has successfully happened
        me.display(Player.display)
```

I'm not sure honestly what the issue is.

For context, everytime the player says "save" and then "y" the game crashes completely and forces you to restart which is obviously not the intention, the same goes for the load system.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: When you save, you are creating a brand new empty player object that happens to have the player's name.  Don't you literally want to pick the `Game.player` object?  And why make it a static method?  If you make it a regular method, then you can just save `self.player`.

Comment: Hey @MarkSouls thanks for the reply. 

According to VSCode here is the error message 

"Exception has occurred: TypeError
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
  File "C:\Users\nanos\Desktop\Python Project\Game.py", line 108, in askSave
    Save = Player(Game.player.name)
  File "C:\Users\nanos\Desktop\Python Project\Game.py", line 94, in input_handler
    Game.askSave()
  File "C:\Users\nanos\Desktop\Python Project\Game.py", line 313, in <module>
    s = Game.input_handler()"

Comment: However, I guess a Player object doesn't actually contain anything.  What is it good for?  Why isn't `CreatePlayer` a static?

Answer (score 0):

Your Character->Player inheritance hierarchy is not designed correctly.  The constructor for Player doesn't call the base class constructor, so none of the class variables get initialized.  I can't try to present a corrected version because I'm not sure what you want to do here.

Your save function will crash on the following line:

```
Save = Player(Game.player.name)
```

because the constructor for Player does not take any arguments.

Some general advice: When a Python program crashes it ALWAYS (well, almost always) prints a traceback message.  This is an incredibly valuable source of information.  Learn how to use it.  And when you're asking a question on SO, ALWAYS give the traceback if there is one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice! I'm taking a summer course on python and this is my summer project.. I may have put in too much scope considering it is the second week of learning Python haha.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Player to this. Get rid of CreatePlayer, because creating a `Player` calls `__init__`:

```
class Player(Character):
    def __init__(self, maxHP, shield, damageAbsorption, attack, dodge, money):
        print("*******************")
        s = input("This is the adventure of ..")
        Character.__init__(self, s, maxHP, shield, damageAbsorption, attack, dodge, money)
```

Then, at the start of Game, do:

```
class Game(object):
    player = None
```

Then, instead of calling CreatePlayer, just instantiate a Player object:

```
    Game.player = Player(5, 2, 0, 1, 5, 50)
```

Then, change askSave() to do:

```
            # Creates the file and puts the data into the file
            pickle.dump(Game.player, open("save.dat", "wb"))
```

And similarly change load() to:

```
    @staticmethod
    def load():
        Game.player = pickle.load(open("save.dat", "rb"))  # Loads the file
        Game.player.show_stat()
```

That will get you most of the way there.

Comment: Thank you so much for this Tim! Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Apologies for the additional question but would adding "self`"` here fix the TypeError? (Exception has occurred: TypeError
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 7 were given)

`Game.player = Player(5, 2, 0, 1, 5, 50)`